# Proper way to autogenerate footer in Django based on models

Tags: python, django

I want to add a complete list of categories (each category is a model) to the bottom of each page in my Django template. I'd like to have it so that it's autogenerated. I'd also rather not have to feed the list of categories from each view.

Is there a proper way to do this so that I don't have to feed it to the template each time?

Answer (score 3):

You could either

**Write a custom template tag:**
Use an [inclusion tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#inclusion-tags) which pulls in all your categories and shows them in a template. Include this template tag in your base template.

```
from django import template
register = template.Library()

from app.models import Category

@register.inclusion_tag("footer.html")
def footer():
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    return {"categories": categories}
```

This is probably your best bet for what you want to do.

**Use a custom context processor:**
[Create a function](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#writing-your-own-context-processors) that pulls in all your categories and makes them available in the template context for all pages.

Answer (score 2):

Create a [template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/howto/custom-template-tags/) add that tag to the base template (or whatever template that has the common footer).